# Contact form spam, without form?

Tags: forms, spam, contact

I previously had a contact page with the theme built-in contact form.
I received a lot of spam with that form, and one day I had to change it to add functionalities (upload to google docs) and I decided to get a JotForm plugin for wordpress.

So I changed the form url, the page url, but I still get a lot of spam from the old page url.

The new page is "/contactezmoi" and the old was "/contact", so i guessed wordpress matched the url to redirect to the new page, but the form sent by mail is the one used on the old contact page.

So let me guess, the spammer don't use the form and call directly the wp-contact page...

What can I do to get rid of thoses unwanted messages ?

Comment: Was the form actually POSTing to the page? If it was using admin endpoint and you still use theme, then said endpoint might be still be happily accepting messages while the form is long gone.

Comment: Yes the form action was the page url (url changed) and i'm still using the same theme, just changed the contact form and contact page url